# is pan-starrs' data available to public users?

Tags: star

Anybody knows that?

The data products are all images or star catalogs?

This is the link:
http://pan-starrs.ifa.hawaii.edu/public/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've to be member of the [PS1 Science Consortium](http://www.ps1sc.org/) to be able to [log in](http://web01.psps.ifa.hawaii.edu/PSI/login.php?referencePage=/PSI/index.php).
And you'll need some [database query](http://psps.ifa.hawaii.edu/psps-trac/attachment/wiki/PsiFigs/query_builder_step4.png) knowledge, at least by using the [PSPS Query Builder](http://psps.ifa.hawaii.edu/psps-trac/wiki/PSIQueryBuilder), or more advanced programming capabilities (XML, SOAP, Python, Perl). A short documentation of the database tables can be found [here](http://web01.psps.ifa.hawaii.edu/psps-trac/wiki/ODMTables).
If you like to dig deeper into the database, [this FAQ](http://web01.psps.ifa.hawaii.edu/psps-trac/wiki/PSPSFAQ) page may be a starting point.

The image processing pipeline (IPP) is described in [this paper](http://www.amostech.com/TechnicalPapers/2006/Pan-STARRS/Magnier.pdf).